# I'm trying to parse an XML using Jackson in Java Springboot and then updating it on a database. I'm a beginner in Java Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, xml-parsing, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm not getting the entire XML file parsed for some reason. I'm not sure where I'm getting the error. Only the last part is being parsed.

Here is the code(ignore the comments):

CPE-item:

```
package com.dependency.demo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlText;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;

@Data
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "cpe-item")
public class CpeItem {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "name",isAttribute = true)
    private String name;


    private String title;


}
```

CPEList:

```
package com.dependency.demo;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlText;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "cpe-list")
public class CpeList {



//    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true,localName = "name")
//    private String name;


@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "cpe-item")
//    private CpeItem cpeItem;
    private CpeItem cpeItems;



}
```

XMLController:

```
package com.dependency.demo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

@RestController
public class XmlController  {
    @GetMapping
    CpeList cpeList() throws XMLStreamException, IOException {

        InputStream xmlResource = XmlController.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.xml");
        XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory =XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(xmlResource);
        XmlMapper mapper= new XmlMapper();
        CpeList cpeList= mapper.readValue(xmlStreamReader,CpeList.class);
//        CpeItem emp1= cpeList.getCpeItems()[0];
//        System.out.println(" "+emp1.getTitle());
//        System.out.println(" "+emp1.getName());


//        for(CpeItem cpeItem : cpeList.getCpeItems())   {
//            cpeItem.getName();
//            cpeItem.getTitle();
//        }
        return cpeList;
    }

}
```

And here is the XML file(we took only a small part here to see if it's working)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<cpe-list>
    <cpe-item name="John">
        <title>xmlread</title>
    </cpe-item>
    <cpe-item name="Jack">
        <title>testtitle</title>
    </cpe-item>
</cpe-list>
```

I tried to do it using the Jackson parser. I'm a beginner and I couldn't get the entire XML parsed. Here is the output I'm getting:

```
<CpeList>
<cpeItems name="Jack">
<title>testtitle</title>
</cpeItems>
</CpeList>
```

For some reason the cpe-item John is not being parsed.

I'm also a beginner in stackoverflow :)

Comment: Hi. You are not showing the code you're using to insert the xml in the database.

Comment: Sorry. I was just returning to see if it's getting parsed properly. I've edited the question. Can you please go through it again?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the annotations should be:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "cpe-list")
public class CpeList {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "cpe-item")
    private List<CpeItem> cpeItem;
...
}
```

Since your list object is the root and there is no other wrapper to the list.
`CpeItem` looks correct to me.